# Errors during creation of OpenGL objects

Tags: c++, opengl

The "Errors" section in the [official docs](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GLAPI/glCreateShader) says "<...> if an error occurs" for certain functions, such as `glCreateShader`, or `glCreateProgram`. Does that imply only the listed possible errors, or does that also include any unlisted internal errors? I'm guessing it's the latter, seeing as the docs say "This function returns 0 if an error occurs creating the program object" for `glCreateProgram`, yet there are no actual possible errors listed. If that is true, is there a way for me to know anything about the potential error in case it happens?

Comment: "is there a way for me to know a little bit more about what exactly might've happened?"...[debug output](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output)?

Comment: @genpfault No, I don't mean the normal, documented errors. I mean the internal ones, such as if glUseProgram returns 0, even though it takes no parameters, and there are no possible errors documented for it.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Oops, I meant glCreateProgram. I basically meant "how can I know what happened" in the case of glCreateProgram returning 0, since there are no errors mentioned in the docs for it.

Comment: @Rabbid76 That was basically what I was curious about: is there a way to find out about errors that aren't reported to glGetError or the debug output. My first thought about why glCreateProgram would return 0 was actually not related to contexts, but rather the GL simply running out of program object names to give, which is of course very unlikely, but should technically be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every OpenGL function can [emit certain errors](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Error#Meaning_of_errors), even if it may not appear to make sense how that particular function could emit that particular error. These errors generally do not represent direct misuse of the API, but instead report a condition that, while you may have caused it, was not necessarily caused by that specific function.

For example, `GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY` can be emitted by any function. Even functions that don't logically allocate memory can emit this error, as running out of memory may happen asynchronously. As such, the driver will only report the OOM condition during whatever OpenGL call happens to occur after the lack of memory is discovered.

Because all OpenGL functions can emit these errors, they are not printed on each function's error section to reduce redundancy. But the function's behavior in the event of an error still needs to be specified.